# Filtrar NAs no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Queria saber como posso incluir as `NA`s do meu dataframe no `filter` do `dplyr`. Exemplo:

```
filter(trabalhadores,C007 == 'Conta própria', C007B == 'Não' | C007B == NA)
```

Queria pegar os que estiverem escrito "Não" e os que estiverem `NA` no dataframe, mas não consigo. Já tentei usando `is.na()` mas ele só filtrava os `NA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi tão bem o que comentou ali no final, mas tente o seguinte:

```
library(dplyr)

trabalhadores <-data.frame(C007B = c("Não","Sim",NA))

  C007B
1   Não
2   Sim
3  <NA>

filter(trabalhadores,C007B == 'Não' | is.na(C007B))

  C007B
1   Não
2  <NA>
```